# FileInfo object property question - C#?

Tags: c#, windows-explorer, system.io.fileinfo

Does the following `System.IO.FileInfo` properties map to the following properties in the Windows Explorer application:

- CreationTime = Date Created
- LastWriteTime = Date Modified
- LastAccessTime = Date Accessed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in a nutshell.

(I'm not sure I can add *anything* else of any use here...)

Comment: Righto - will remove that bit from my answer.